# could not convert string to float

Tags: python, arduino

Al ejecutar el codigo me arroja este tipo de error:

```
value = float(serialConnection.readline().strip())

Could not convert string to float: b'Humedad: 54.30%\tTemperatura: 26.20\xc2\xb0C\t79.16\xc2\xb0F'
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour]. ¿Qué esperas que te devuelva?

Comment: Es un texto, no la representación del valor.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes es una coleccion de `bytes` (el prefijo b lo indica)

Primero necesitas decodificar el mensaje a un string:

```
>>> texto_inicial = serialConnection.readline().strip()

b'Humedad: 54.30%\tTemperatura: 26.20\xc2\xb0C\t79.16\xc2\xb0F'

>>> decodificado = texto_inicial.decode()

'Humedad: 54.30%\tTemperatura: 26.20°C\t79.16°F'
```

Ahora usa `.split()` para separar los tokens

```
>>> lista_tokens = decodificado.split()

['Humedad:', '54.30%', 'Temperatura:', '26.20°C', '79.16°F']
```

(Puedes concatenar operaadores en un solo paso y hacer `lista_tokens = texto_inicial.decode().split()` pero si estas empezando es mas facil entender cada paso si lo haces individualmente y ves el resultado)

Finalmente puedes convertir la humedad y temperatura a numeros

```
# segundo elemento (indice 1), quitamos el ultimo caracter (%)
>>> valor_humedad = float(lista_tokens[1][:-1])

54.3

# cuarto elemento (indice 3), quitamos los dos ultimos caracteres (°C)
>>> valor_temperatura_c = float(lista_tokens[3][:-2])

26.20

# quinto elemento (indice 4), quitamos los dos ultimos caracteres (°F)
>>> valor_temperatura_f = float(lista_tokens[4][:-2])

79.16
```

Ahora tienes los valores numericos de humedad y temperatura en las variables

`valor_humedad`, `valor_temperatura_c` y `valor_temperatura_f`

Comment: Excelente respuesta, lo que no sabemos es si esto es lo que quiere lograr el AP, que hasta ahora no ha respondido a la retroalimentación que se le dio. Yo usualmente trato de responder a preguntas bien formadas. Te invito a leer [answer] y, por qué no [ask]. Un saludo y gracias por aportar a la comunidad :)